# String Array for string.xml android

Tags: android

I'm doing some age calculation using spinner.
I've added string array to it.
In my string array in string.xml, 
I key in the value

```
 <string-array name="arrayAge">
        <item> < 40 </item>
        <item> >=40 </item>

    </string-array>
```

However, I met with error at <40.
Can anyone tell me how should I format it,
if I want to display <40?

Comment: Did you try to put `&lt;` instead of the `<`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `&lt;` if you want to display `<` character. The reason for it is that in XML, `<` is the beginning of the closing tag and the parser wouldn't know how to distinguish that.

To display `>`, use `&gt;`.

Comment: If I'm putting > , I can just display > character is it?

Comment: You need to use &gt to display > symbol    Only the characters "<" and "&" are strictly illegal in XML. The greater than character is legal, but it is a good habit to replace it.

Answer (score 5):

for less then(<) symbol `&lt;` or `&#8804;` for Less Than or Equal To Sign and  for greater than(>) symbol `&gt;` (or) `&#8805;` for Greater Than or Equal To Sign.

Comment: for = , I can use that character right?
like
from >= 40
to
&gt = 40 
??

Comment: you can use &ge for greater than or equal to and &le for less than or equal to..

Comment: there's an error occurs, if I use &ge;

Comment: i have edited the answer... you can seee

Comment: &GreaterEqual;   you can try even this also.....

Answer (score 2):

try this by replacing

this

```
    <string-array name="arrayAge">
            <item> < 40 </item>
            <item> >=40 </item>

    </string-array>
```

with:

```
<string-array name="arrayAge">
        <item> &lt;40</item>
        <item> &gt;=40 </item>

</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
”   => &#34; 或 &quot;

’   => &#39; 或 &apos;

&   => &#38; 或 &amp;

<   => &#60; 或 &lt；

>   => &62; 或 &gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant declare special character like this"<40"

What you have to do is simple <40
And for >=40 you have to use it >=40